# Axes Title Angle and Show Time In Multiple Axes using TeeChart Javascript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, teechart

Using  `TeeChart Javascript/HTML5`

```
Chart1.axes.items[0] = Chart1.axes.left;      
Chart1.axes.items[4] = Chart1.axes.add(false,false);
```

1. When first loading,it will show Only Chart1.axes.items[0].Title.Text
   Until `MouseMove`,it show Chart1.axes.items[4].Title.Text ,Chart1.axes.items[5].Title.Text...etc

   Can any solution show all Axes Title in first loading at on time?
2. In Y Axes,Axes.Title comes always in Vertical,I want it be on Horizontal

   And any method set Axes.Title.Angle or turn it to Horizontal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. When first loading,it will show Only Chart1.axes.items[0].Title.Text
>      Until MouseMove,it show Chart1.axes.items[4].Title.Text
>      ,Chart1.axes.items[5].Title.Text...etc
>
>    Can any solution show all Axes Title in first loading at on time?

We've fixed it for the next maintenance release. Thanks for reporting it.

> 1. In Y Axes,Axes.Title comes always in Vertical,I want it be on Horizontal
>
>    And any method set Axes.Title.Angle or turn it to Horizontal?

We've implemented a new rotation property for the all the axes titles.

```
Chart1.axes.left.title.rotation = 90;
```

This will also be available with the next maintenance release and will work with 0, 90 and 270 degrees by now.